# How do I delete an entry from an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

I have the xml information populate in a listBox(lstAnimals).  I can delete from the listBox with the following code:

```
 private void btnAdopt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Complete Adoption?", "Found a Happy Home!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            if (lstAnimals.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                lstAnimals.Items.Remove(lstAnimals.SelectedItem);                                                        

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

However, when the list is updated/program opened, that entry repopulates into the listBox.  How can I delete this from the XML document simultaneously with the lixtBox?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Animals>
  <Animal>
   <Name>Bruce</Name>
   <Type>Dog</Type>
   <Age>Adult</Age>
  </Animal>
  <Animal>
   <Name>Gizmo</Name>
   <Type>Cat</Type>
   <Age>Senior</Age>
  </Animal>
 </Animals>
```

I was asked how I populate my listBox, so here is the code:

```
private void UpdateList() 
    {         
        var an = XElement.Load(@"Animals.xml")
            .Descendants("Animal")
            .OrderBy(xe => (xe.Element("Name").Value))
            .ToList<XElement>();

        lstAnimals.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var a in an)
            lstAnimals.Items.Add(new Animal()
            {
                name = a.Element("Name").Value.ToString(),
                type = a.Element("Type").Value,
                age = a.Element("Age").Value
            });
    }
```

Picture of what the listBox presents as:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v84/Shades9323/shelterapp_zps4c22868c.jpg

Comment: Show your code with the ListBox. How it is populated and the delete/update

Comment: You probably deserialized the xml into your object. You have to serialize it again and save over the old one.

Comment: I edited with the code that populates my listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code into your button click event

```
        string text = lstAnimals.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string animalName = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("is")).Trim();           
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Animals.xml"); //here is your filepath
        XElement element = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("Animal")
            where x.Element("Name").Value == animalName  
            select x).First();
        element.Remove();
        xDoc.Save("Animals.xml");
        lstAnimals.Items.Remove(lstAnimals.SelectedItem);
```

Ofcourse if you add Id property to your animals,it will be easier.Just store id variable into your listBox Items "Tag" property..

Comment: Visual studio won't let me add .Text or .SubItems after the .selected item. Might I be missing a using statement?

Comment: I have a string that reads "name" is a "type" who is a(n) "age" in the list box.  I'll try your edit.

Comment: Tried it( put in if (lstAnimals.SelectedIndex >=0) and got the following exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: can you share your listbox photo??

Comment: here is a link to the pic:  http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v84/Shades9323/shelterapp_zps4c22868c.jpg

Comment: that gives me an exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the string name line

Comment: edited for last time,i didn't know your listBox content,you shared your code but you didn't mention about string like this,

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this.  Still trying to figure out the best information to get my questions answered.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Does it worked now? don't forget filepaths must be same

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.  I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" still.

Comment: check your filePath, i assume your xml file in the same directory with your exe,i mean debug folder,where is your file and what is it name??

Comment: I have been using (@"Animals") for the filePath.  The file is located in bin -> Debug -> Animals.xml

Comment: ok,it should work now i typed animals.xml your filename's first letter is uppercase

Comment: I picked up on that earlier!  I have been using Animals.xml the whole time. :)  Here is a picture of my code.  Maybe I have something in the wrong place? http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v84/Shades9323/code_zps245440e1.jpg

Comment: It gets hung up on the string text line with that same exception.  Again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: yes i see your code,you remove the item before you try to get value,copy your Remove code to end of method scope

Comment: Like so: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v84/Shades9323/code2_zpsc9dcbc61.jpg  That seems to get closer.  Now I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the where statement.

Comment: Don't type xDoc.Descendants("Animals"), it should be  xDoc.Descendants("Animal")

Comment: It finally works!  Thank You so very much!  And a big thanks for sticking with me until the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XmlDocument removeChild** method similar to this

```
XmlDocument doc ;

doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("path to your XML file");

XmlNode animalNode;
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

animalNode=root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::Animal[Name='" + lstAnimals.SelectedItem + "']");
doc.RemoveChild(animalNode) ;

//save the XML file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how  you  can do it using linq to xml

```
     private void btnAdopt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Complete Adoption?", "Found a Happy Home!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            if (lstAnimals.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
                lstAnimals.Items.Remove(lstAnimals.SelectedItem);  
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
            xDoc.Descendants("Animal").Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value.ToString() == lstAnimals.SelectedItem ).Remove();
            xDoc.Save("test1.xml"); 

}                                                      

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. It is still leaving the entry in the xml document.